# fs.unlink not deleting file in local folder after updating item

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I try to update posts but fs.unlink() doesen't remove the older files in my local folder. In my collection, the image path seem to be updated as the old path is replaced. I don't know why the old images are still retained in my local folder. The update controller works since everything else gets updated.

I use this function for the deletion

```
        const clearImage = filePath => {
        filePath = path.join(__dirname, "..", filePath);
        fs.unlink = (filePath, err => console.log(err));
```

I call `clearImage` here:

```
Post.findById(postId)
        .then(post => {
            if (!post) {
                const error = new Error('Could not find post');
                error.statusCode = 404;
                throw error
            }

            if (imageUrl == !post.imageUrl) {
                clearImage(post.imageUrl);
            }

            post.title = title;
            post.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            post.content = content;
            return post.save();

        })
```

Comment: `fs.unlink = …`. You're assigning something to `fs.unlink`, not _calling_ it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare strings like this:

```
if (imageUrl !== post.imageUrl)
```

instead of this:

```
if (imageUrl == !post.imageUrl)
```

And call the `unlink` function like this:

```
fs.unlink(filePath, err => console.log(err));
```

Instead of this:

```
fs.unlink = (filePath, err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: @Saliko No problem, to debug your code, try to use `console.log()` after/before each line you suspect to see if the code reaches there!